# Is there a way to recover permanently deleted autodesk account

Tags: autodesk

I would like to ask if there is a way to recover a permanently deleted account?

if none, how can i create a new account because whenever i try to make a new account using new email, it says "maximum number of verification attempts was reached and we were unable to confirm your eligibility"